# Pandas combine rows based on condition or dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataset

```
+─────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+
| product_name                    | column_value_1  | column_value_2  | column_value_3  | column_value_4  |
+─────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+
| Coca Cola 1L                    | 1               | NaN             | 2               | NaN             |
| Carbonated drink Coca Cola 1L   | NaN             | 1.8             | NaN             | 1               |
| Yellow Cheese                   | NaN             | 5               | NaN             | NaN             |
| Packed Yellow Cheese            | NaN             | NaN             | NaN             | 4.5             |
| Packed Yellow Cheese 1KG        | 3               | NaN             | NaN             | NaN             |
+─────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+
```

I know that `'Coca Cola 1L'`, `'Carbonated drink Coca Cola 1L'` are the same products such as `'Yellow Cheese'`, `'Packed Yellow Cheese'` and `'Packed Yellow Cheese 1KG'` and I want to combine their column values in a dataset which holds the info per product in only 1 row. I'm trying to get following dataset.

```
+─────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+
| product_name                    | column_value_1  | column_value_2  | column_value_3  | column_value_4  |
+─────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+
| Coca Cola 1L                    | 1               | 1.8             | 2               | 1               |
| Packed Yellow Cheese 1KG        | 3               | 5               | NaN             | 4.5             |
+─────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+─────────────────+
```

How this is achievable? I'm also looking for a solution where I can use a dictionary of similar products.

Comment: What is the logic to combine one and oneee, and two, twwo, twooo, etc? For a human this is simple (and onee will probably join the first group and twwoo the second), for a machine you need some logic or a dictionary or something... Are there always 0 or more duplicates of a syllable in the right order? In that case, you might be able to do something with regex...

Comment: You need to use some library like 'nltk' and get corrected words for product_name in another column, then groupby that column then do aggregation like sum.

Comment: Hi Niels Henkens and @SomeDude , this is true for human is easy, that's why I have created product similarity matrix based on Levenshtein distance. Now I have to combine some rows based on the matrix similarity which I'm planning to transpose to dictionaries.

Comment: Can you provide a real life example?

Comment: @mozway I have changed the tables given above

Comment: Ok then you need to use fuzzy matching, or clustering. It's quite easy, you have plenty of examples on this site. But this is also highly dependent on the real data, so you have to try and see, you likely won't get a perfect solution here without the real data.

Comment: Hi @mozway I've build my own dataset with products which are similar, fuzzy matching or whatever solution it is out of scope for this question. Now I'm looking for a way where I'm supplying a dictionary of products for which I know they are the same and I want to combine the rows based on this dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you somehow know which products are the same and you have this relationship in a map such as:

```
products_map = {
    "Carbonated drink Coca Cola 1L": "Coca Cola 1L",
    "Coca Cola 1L": "Coca Cola 1L",
    "Yellow Cheese": "Packed Yellow Cheese 1 KG",
    "Packed Yellow Cheese": "Packed Yellow Cheese 1 KG",
    "Packed Yellow Cheese 1KG": "Packed Yellow Cheese 1 KG"
}
```

You can apply this map to the pandas series with a `df.product_name.map(products_map)`. After that you just need to do a groupby by this column and aggregate the values as you wish.

Comment: Hi, could you supply the whole logic, for now I'm ending up with weird object instead of dataframe with mapping.

Comment: @default_settings, the map method of a pd.Series returns another pd.Series, with the correspondent values changed. So you can do something like `df.loc[:, "product_name"] = df.product_name.map(products_map)`

You can read more about it on the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: Hi @Gabriel could you supply the whole code, I'm still trying to make this work for a larger dataset. Afterthat I can accept your answer as a solution.

Comment: `products_map = {
    "Carbonated drink Coca Cola 1L": "Coca Cola 1L",
    "Coca Cola 1L": "Coca Cola 1L",
    "Yellow Cheese": "Packed Yellow Cheese 1 KG",
    "Packed Yellow Cheese": "Packed Yellow Cheese 1 KG",
    "Packed Yellow Cheese 1KG": "Packed Yellow Cheese 1 KG"
}

df.loc[:, "product_name"] = df.product_name.map(products_map)`

This is the only code you need - besides that you only need to write on the dictionary the relation between your products, given that you know them all. After that you just need to aggreagate the columns with a groupby.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, I am here to try to help you, so I will give you this solution and maybe it will work with you, but I don't know if this will help you if you have a lot of data, but this will give you an idea.

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {"product_name":['one', 'oneee', 'two', 'twwo', 'twooo'],
        "column_value_1":[1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3],
        "column_value_2":[np.nan, 1.8, 5, np.nan, np.nan],
        "column_value_3":[2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        "column_value_4":[np.nan, 1, np.nan, 4.5, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[df['product_name'].str.contains("one"), "product_name"] = "one"
df.loc[df["product_name"] != "one", "product_name"] = "two"  # Or ['two','two','two']

print(df.groupby("product_name").sum())

# You can make a new variable and store the last result in it

new_df = df.groupby("product_name").sum()

# if you want to nan values instead of 0.0

# new_df.replace(0.0, np.nan, inplace=True)

# print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                  column_value_1  column_value_2  column_value_3  column_value_4
product_name                                                                
one                      1.0             1.8             2.0             1.0
two                      3.0             5.0             0.0             4.5
```

**Updated**

Here is another way that will help you:

```
import numpy as np
import textblob as blob
import pandas

data = {"product_name": ['one', 'oneee', 'two', 'twwo', 'twooo'],
        "column_value_1": [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3],
        "column_value_2": [np.nan, 1.8, 5, np.nan, np.nan],
        "column_value_3": [2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        "column_value_4": [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 4.5, np.nan]}


names = data.get("product_name")

for name, i in zip(names, range(len(names))):
    names[i] = blob.Word(name).correct()

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
new_df = df.groupby("product_name").sum()
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  product_name  column_value_1  column_value_2  column_value_3  column_value_4
0          one             1.0             1.8             2.0             1.0
1          two             3.0             5.0             0.0             4.5
```

Hope to help you,

Comment: Hi @Mohammad how can I achieve this using dictionary?

Comment: The new answer is done, don't forget to accept the answer and vote, thank you.